# Frontend Form Validation from Backend Functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, forms, validation, dynamic

I have a series of form elements that can be created on the client side by the request of the server in response to some event. (Server and client are written in Typescript) The elements are pretty generic like 'input', 'confirm', 'checkbox' and I have had success passing along parameters to the client. However, I cannot figure out a best-practice of how to pass the validators for the form element to the client. My use-case prevents me from including the validators in the client code upfront.

Options I have considered so far:

- Putting the validator in a separate file and allowing it to be dynamically `import()`ed
- Passing the validator to the frontend by `JSON.stringify(f.toString())` and de-serializing by `new Function('return ' + JSON.parse(payload))();`

Is there a better way to pass/serialize these validator functions from the server to the client that I am missing (considering both developer experience and security)? How could I populate the scope on the client side as well?